# JDBC: Get table list calling method getTables of DatabaseMetadata with advanced table pattern

Tags: jdbc

I want to call getTables method of DatabaseMetaData and get all tables which names are not starting with "KB".

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `getTables()` accepts (only) standard SQL patterns for a `LIKE` condition, I don't think this is possible.

Some DBMS violate (aka "extend") the SQL standard by allowing regular expressions for a `LIKE` condition (I think SQL Server does this).

Check the manual for your DBMS what kind of expressions LIKE supports.

If it *does* support a regular expression you can try to use `^[^KB].*` as the filter condition for the table name parameter. But again this is non-standard and won't work on all DBMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot

I think I must write Java regular expression to match list of needed table names matched with "%" pattern.