# Match strings with regular expression in ignore case

Tags: java, regex

I need to match strings in my array which are not starting with "KB" string.
I have tried this

```
String[] ar = {"KB_aaa","KB_BBB", "K_CCC", "!KBD", "kb_EEE", "FFFF"};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^(^KB)].*");

for(String str : ar)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.matches())
         System.out.println(str);
}
```

But it still not matches "K_CCC".
Thanks

Comment: Related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659449/jdbc-get-table-list-calling-method-gettables-of-databasemetadata-with-advanced-t

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regex that matches anything *not* starting with KB is:

```
^(?!KB).*
```

To do it in java:

```
if (str.matches("^(?!KB).*$")) ...
```

Answer (score 36):

I wouldn't use RegEx for everything.

```
for(String str : ar)
{
    if(!str.toUpperCase().startsWith("KB"))
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Because it can be not only KB and can be complex expression, for now I need this :)

Comment: That's case sensitive. I think he wanted a case *insensitive* match.

Comment: @Jon and others: You get the idea. It isn't too difficult to change the condition to `!str.toUpperCase().startsWith("KB")`!

Answer (score 29):

From the way your question is worded, I'm not entirely sure whether you want the match to be case insensitive or not. This regex:

```
(?i)[^k][^b].*
```

uses the flag (?i) to turn off case sensitivity, and should do want you want.

Comment: honestly I think this is the correct answer -- I think the question is broader in the sense how do you tell the RE engine to ignore case

Comment: This is not the right answer. Your pattern will NOT match a string like aw234 or vj2345

Answer (score 11):

```
    String[] ar = {"KB_aaa","KB_BBB", "K_CCC", "!KBD", "kb_EEE", "FFFF"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^KB.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    for(String str : ar)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if(!m.matches())
             System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use RegExes everywhere. Just create a simple check:

```
for (String str : ar)
{
    if (!str.toLowerCase().startsWith("kb"))
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

And I think, that this method is even better in performace (not that performance is needed in your case):

```
public static boolean accept(String name)
{
    if (name.length() < 2) return true;
    String sub = name.substring(0, 2);
    return !sub.equalsIgnoreCase("KB");
}
```

What do others thing of this second way of working?

Comment: No I need it with regex :) This is just a simple example to simply not match Strings which are starting with KB

Answer (score 4):

Use the regex `(?i)^(?!kb).*` for case insensitive matches. It will avoid KB234 Kb*432, kB2343 and kb23445.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet that can help for the ignore case understanding with String.matches function, for further details please use this [link][1]

```
String stringToSearch = "Four score and seven years ago our fathers ...";

// this won't work because the pattern is in upper-case
System.out.println("Try 1: " + stringToSearch.matches(".*SEVEN.*"));

// the magic (?i:X) syntax makes this search case-insensitive, so it returns true
System.out.println("Try 2: " + stringToSearch.matches("(?i:.*SEVEN.*)"));
```

> ```
> Try 1: false
> Try 2: true
> ```

[1]: [http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-how-case-insensitive-search-string-matches-method/#:~:text=Solution%3A%20Use%20the%20String%20matches,must%20match%20the%20entire%20string.](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-how-case-insensitive-search-string-matches-method/#:%7E:text=Solution%3A%20Use%20the%20String%20matches,must%20match%20the%20entire%20string.))